# I was part of a research work, but not going to be included in the paper

Tags: publications, authorship, research-misconduct

I'm a student. I was part of a collaboration with a different lab. I worked extensively with another student (and sometimes alone) for several months to produce material that was later used in the other lab. After finishing that, I moved to a different lab to continue my studies. Today I realized that the project is going to be published soon, but no one talked with me.

I feel that I contributed enough to be part of that paper since the material I participated in making was part of that collaborative research. What should I do?

I got a message from the PI that according to "McNutt et al., Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, Feb 2018" I do not stand for all conditions, therefore not eligible for that credit.

Again, I don't understand anything in those political rules, all I know is that the material I made and worked on for several monthes was a significant part in the later experiments. I can't understand the reason why not to include me.

Comment: Have you talked to the authors and shared these thoughts?

Comment: This paper wasn't officially published yet, and no I didn't talk with them yet. I'm about to do that really soon.

Comment: Nothing much else to do until you've done that.

Comment: "I worked extensively with another student (and sometimes alone)" Are the supervisors and PIs responsible for the paper actually aware of that in general and specifically of the extent of your work?

Comment: So i talked with the PI: I'm not quailified to be part of the paper .

Comment: @Noname did they give a reason as to why you're not qualified?

Comment: Yes...the Pi said that according to "McNutt et al., Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, Feb 2018" I'm not qualified to all conditions together. This is weird for me, I significantly contributed to the preparation of a material that was later used in the other collaboration lab. I also have proof for that. I also cannot understand the reason why not to include me, since I actually worked on that for several months.

Comment: @justauser For example, since I didn't "approve the submitted version" or something weird like that, it's like I'm not part of it.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I talked with the PI, feels like I'm getting weird answers...

Comment: Ask the PI for their advice on how you should present your work in a CV. Also ask them whether they think they could,  in the future, write you a good letter of recommendation for your work. Don't burn bridges over this.

Comment: If you're not one of the authors (which, if you contributed directly to the work, you probably should be), then you should be mentioned in the acknowledgements *at the very least*.

Comment: @isolatedmatrix the other student that worked with me did the same work and he's included as an author...what should I do if I don't get it?

Comment: I can't tell you what you *should* do, because I'm probably not the best judge. You could speak to some of the other authors and see what they think (particularly the other student). You could also go to another academic you trust, or the head of department, and discuss it with them.

Answer (score 7):

Have a conversation with the lead author or PI about your participation and whether you contributed enough to earn authorship. It is hard to say what the outcome will be, but you, at least, likely deserve an acknowledgement for your work.

The decision will (should) be based on whether your participation contribute intellectual, creative, content or, instead, was work at the direction of others. The first earns authorship. The other may not, but at least an acknowledgement.

Talk to them. Make your case.

However, it isn't just hard work and effort that makes you an author. More is needed: contributions to the intellectual content.

A couple of examples where hard work likely doesn't result in authorship:

If someone, A, designs an experiment requiring recording interviews and B carries out those interviews at the direction of A, the B might not be an author.

If B creates a physical model from blueprints designed by A for some applied project, the B might not be an author.

If B writes a computer program from a solid design by A, then B might not be an author.

If B is paid for work in some research project the B might not be an author.

And some feel that undergraduates, especially, are "paid" in the learning they get from participation. I won't necessarily condone that, but it happens.

Comment: Even if it was work at the direction of others, it qualifies the OP for authorship as the OP did a substantial amount of work for several months and he/she is only a student so can't be expected to do much else at this stage.

Comment: I talked about it. I'm not qualified to be included according to what I've been told by the PI. Even though I contributed to producing the material used in the paper

Comment: @Buffy, although my status is a student,  I did not do that work as a undergraduate student. I did that work as part of the mission I got from the PI because they needed to close that gap in order to send that material to the collaborators. I indeed was working with another student, I wasn't learning from him, but we worked together.

Comment: Here is a fairly common view on requirements for authorship. Some others omit the second bullet(as I would): https://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html

Comment: "Final approval of the version to be published", if it means for the material itself than yes Im accountable for all.

Comment: I disagree with your list of instances where you think someone wouldn't deserve authorship. I think in every one of those circumstances the person doing the grunt work should absolutely get authorship but maybe not the first author. The person who conceived the idea and designed the experiments should obviously get the first author but it makes no sense to exclude someone. Science is inclusive and collaborative not exclusive. I always advocate erring on the side of giving credit rather than not. The OP absolutely should be part of this paper

Comment: @sarat.kant, welcome to the site. You are free to disagree, of course, but I'll stick with what I wrote. Authorship requires creativity IMO. I won't judge the OPs contribution here, but that should be the general idea.